# how to calculate startdate=today-30 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing one stored procedure, i need to pass start and end date as parameters, by default start name should be 30 days prior to the today's date. Give me some suggestions to do this..

startdate=today-30 days.
enddate=today.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Declare @startdate datetime
```

`set @startdate = DATEADD(day,-30,getdate())` will give you your start date

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

If u prefer to use **Date** datatype:

```
   set @startdate=dateadd(day,-30,convert(date,getdate()))
    set @enddate= convert(date,getdate())
```

Comment: just to add to this, if you prefer to use a date datatype: `declare @startdate as date;set @startdate = dateadd(d, -30, GETDATE());select @startdate;`

Answer (score 1):

Look at DATEADD passing in -30 for movement  and d as date part parameter. Am not near a computer to give you full syntax

Comment: there is also stackoverflow for mobile phones ;)

Comment: @SeanW - I'd guess he means he's on a smart phone, not sure.  I hope he doesn't inbuilt WiFi or 3G!

Comment: I know, I know. I was just being silly. (Because in my mind, smartphones ARE computers...). @Dems - exactly! That's what I was thinking! :)

Comment: Was actually on my smartphone and not near a computer with sql to be able to check full syntax. Inbuilt WiFi - will have to investigate that :)

Answer (score 1):

`select DATEADD(dd,-30,getdate())`
will give you start date. and `select getdate()` will give you enddate(current date) if you want to pass the end date from the front end then just replace the **getdate()** with Enddate coming from front end.